# How to print the output of the get_num_queries function from frontend to backend?

Tags: admin, query

I'm trying to develop a simple plugin and figure out how to display the number of queries executed  in frontend, to an admin page (plugin options page), using [get_num_queries()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_num_queries) function.

I've added the following code to my plugin's function file and works well showing (in my footer) the number of queries processed to create the frontend page:

```
function get_queries() {
$get_queries ='';
$get_queries .= get_num_queries();
$get_queries .= ' queries';
echo $get_queries;
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'get_queries', 999);
```

If I use `echo get_queries();` in the place where I want to display the value in my plugin page, it display the number of queries processed in the plugin options page, not from frontend.

My question is: how to print the number of queries processed to create the frontend page in my plugin options page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each HTTP request is a new one so you will need to save the data to the database. You can't just "pass" the data from the front to the back end.

```
function get_queries_wpse_143544() {
  $dbq = get_num_queries();
  update_option('page_queries',$dbq);
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'get_queries_wpse_143544', 999);
```

Then retrieve the data with [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

Comment: Is there a way to perform a "hidden" HTTP request on frontend on plugin activation since it not dispay any values if no user visit the site? Should I ask a new Question?

Comment: You can do thAT with AJAX.